# Build Failed on app:preDebugBuild (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and I am currently struggling with some error when building a project. to my friend's unit, this is working no problem but to mine, when I am building the project. it says this:

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find firebase-iid-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/16.0.0/firebase-iid-interop-16.0.0.aar
```

and also this error pops up when i sync project with gradle:

[image]

this is my build.gradle(Project:ProjectName)
[image]

this is my build.gradle(Module:App):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `google()` in `build.gradle` Project

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

1.In your module Gradle file (usually the `app/build.gradle`), add the `apply plugin(apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services')` line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin.

2.You should also add the dependencies for the `Firebase com.google.firebase:firebase-core` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` SDK's:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Make sure you have the latest version of 'Google Play services' and 'Google Repository' installed while using Firebase.

Please follow below steps to install:

1.Open Android studio

2.Go to the Menu bar > `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`

3.Click on Tab `> SDK Tools`

4.Check and install `'Google Play Services'` and `'Google Repository'`

5.Click on Apply and wait for the download

If you installed `Google Repository` and `Google Play` your sdk section in android-studio should like this :
[image]

Finally, Sync and build your project again.

Then after that do this solution below , if any of this don't work do another.

-Find your App folder and in this find `gradlew.bat` open it and type :

```
gradlew clean
```

Also you can clean in android-studio menu by go to `Build->Clean Project`

-Disable your anti-virus if you have

-Disable instant-run by go to `Android Studio Settings or Preferences   -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.`

-Sync project with gradle file `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

-Restart android-studio by `Files -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"`

-If any of above solution don't work do this
Go to your **User Folder** - on Windows 7/8 this would be

`:\Users\[your username]` (ex. `C:\Users\David\`)
In this folder you find a folder called `.AndroidStudioBeta` or `.AndroidStudio`
First backup this folder and then remove it.

This should reset your Android-studio settings.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer but im stuck at step 1. The gradlew.bat is closing on its own when i open it

Comment: Clean your project from android studio go to build->clean project. if one of this dont work do another way it probably work .I edit my answer

Comment: Remember this solution not step by step ! you can do each without doing another

Comment: Ok. After cleaning, it gave me the exact same error

Comment: This is written also in build: Could not find firebase-iid-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid-interop/16.0.0/firebase-iid-interop-16.0.0.aar

Comment: is support repository the same with google repository?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182488/discussion-between-ali-khaki-and-kurt-estacion).

Comment: Still not working, is the problem in gradle? since this project is from somewhere else and it is on gradle form like 7mb but when opened in android its way more higher mb,

Comment: Yes. infact there is no problem with my project.

Comment: There problem is the same on the picture above the question.

Comment: @kurtestacion add your gradle.project and gradle.app to the question.probably some library you should add